# If product quantity is zero display none "Open cart"

Tags: php, opencart

I have a shipping info timer on my product page, how can i not display it if my stock is zero, i am running opencart 1.5.5.1. this is my file :
catalog\controller\product\product.php

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
                $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
            } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
                $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
            } else {
                $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
            }
```

This is the coundown timer code
catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/product/product.tpl

```
    <div  class="cdbox";>
<span class="cdbox_2";>
<img src="../image/data/delivery_van_sml.png">
</span>
<span class="cdbox_0";>
Order Within the next&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<br>
<span id="countdownTimer">
00:00.<small>
00</small>
</span>
      <p>
<span class="cdbox_1";>
We guarantee same-day Shipping (Monday&nbsp;&#45;&nbsp;Friday) Before 2pm</p>
</span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/journal2/js/caseSensitiveCountdownTimer.js">
</script>
```

If product quantity is zero i do not want to show the Script. Can anyone help me solve this please.

Comment: Just use a conditional statement in your tpl file

Comment: This is my catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/product/product.tpl  <span class="p-stock"><?php echo $text_stock; ?></span> <span class="journal-stock <?php echo isset($stock_status) ? $stock_status : ''; ?>"><?php echo $stock; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a stock flag to controller (if there is no other way to get it in tpl) wrap your HTML/JS snippet in PHP conditional statement.

Try something like below:

**Not tested**

In controller:

```
 $this->data['in_stock'] = false;
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
        } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
            $this->data['in_stock'] = true;
        } else {
            $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
            $this->data['in_stock'] = true;
        }
```

In tpl:

```
<?php if($in_stock) { ?>

<div  class="cdbox";>
<span class="cdbox_2";>
<img src="../image/data/delivery_van_sml.png">
</span>
<span class="cdbox_0";>
Order Within the next&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<br>
<span id="countdownTimer">
00:00.<small>
00</small>
</span>
      <p>
<span class="cdbox_1";>
We guarantee same-day Shipping (Monday&nbsp;&#45;&nbsp;Friday) Before 2pm</p>
</span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/journal2/js/caseSensitiveCountdownTimer.js">
</script>

<?php } ?>
```